# Show last post when clicked like twitter

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to figure out how to show latest data like twitter.
we know that twitter only show latest data if user click to open it, 
I guess the flow is like some tweets are collected, and when users click its notificatoion, user will see the latest posts.

HTML code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <h3>this is football feed</h3>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" >
            <div id="notification">New feeds coming!</div>
            <div id="opened"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code

```
<script>
    //hide notification div
    $("#notification").hide();
    $("#opened").show();

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8890');
    socket.on('message', function (data) 
    {
        var content = JSON.parse(data); 
        var interests = content['interests'];
        if (interests.search(content['category']) > -1) 
        {
            $("#notification").show();

            $("#notification").click(function(){
                $("#opened").prepend( "<p>"+content['message']+"</p>" );
                $("#notification").hide();
            });
        };
     });
</script>
```

when a post come, it works by showing "New feeds coming" and when I click, it show the last post I get, but if I click it again, it show the same data.

what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

`socket.on()` always goes with `socket.emit()` , 
maybe you need to trigger a related event with `socket.emit()` when user click the button .